# How can I intercept XMPP traffic on Android?

Tags: android, proxy, xmpp

I have been learning about security testing on Android apps, and to intercept traffic I was using Burp Suite. I know it works perfectly for HTTP/HTTPS traffic, but most of the messenger apps are using the XMPP protocol for their communication.

I did a little research on how XMPP works, the relationship with Jabber and all. What I lack is a tool to intercept the XMPP traffic. Burp Suite is unable to intercept the XMPP traffic. I heard about xmpppeak and IMSpector but I didn't try them. I would like to know what tools can intercept XMPP traffic.

I understand tool recommendation is not entertained on Stack Exchange, but still I believe it's a common requirement as attacks on Android apps are rising high these days.

Comment: This might be on-topic on [SoftwareRecs.SE]. I'm not active there, so I can't be certain, but it sounds specific enough.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks for the recommendation. I posted it here because I feel its a security related application.

Comment: @AnanduMDas did you find any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess set up a VPN-server of your own, connect your phone to it and intercept everything with wireshark could work given that you have the neccesairy certificates or are able to MITM yourself with a fake TLS certificate.

Alternatively one of the many tcpdump-alternatives for android for use with wireshark?

Comment: Wireshark is not that user friendly for a security tester. I am looking for something like Burp or Webscarab. :)

Comment: I am not sure XMPP is supported by burp as it is not an HTTP-protocol  ( http://forum.portswigger.net/thread/587/failed-parse-first-line-request )

Comment: I know that and thats the problem I mentioned in question :P

Comment: yeah, hehe remember, that's why I said wireshark.. Moday hitting me hard. Did you check out this wireshark plugin:https://code.google.com/p/xmpp-dissector/ ? Have not tried it out myself.